Handicapped guy has a dancer wife
I only remember one scene from the movie since it was ages ago. American\English movie, saw it on TV (but I don't think it's a TV movie) in mid 80's to mid 90's. Male white actor, dark hair, sad looking eyes. The woman in the movie was hot looking, slim body, long dark hair (I think she's a dancer in the movie).
The man meets the woman, but somehow later in their relationship, he ends up in a wheelchair. The wife starts cheating and comes home with a male black dancer after some party on a cruiseboat. The guy in the wheelchair wears a red fez (that funny looking red hat); she shows up how high he can put his leg, wheelchair guy gets pissed later and kills the wife.

Do you know what year it was approximately from? Where\when did you see it? I'm pretty sure I know what you're after and this would really help...

on tv (but i dont think its tv movie) mid 80´to mid 90

Sounds like Roman Polanski's Bitter Moon from 1992. From Wiki:

A prim and proper British couple, Nigel (Hugh Grant) and Fiona Dobson (Kristin Scott Thomas), are on a Mediterranean cruise ship to Istanbul, en route to India. On the ship, they meet the seductive French [dancer] Mimi (Emmanuelle Seigner) and her much older American husband Oscar (Peter Coyote), a paraplegic: acerbic and cynical, he is jaded and a failure as a writer. The story unfolds as Oscar invites Nigel to his cabin, and tells him in great detail how he and Mimi first met on a bus in Paris and fell passionately in love.

Oscar kills Mimi in the end. Here's Oscar (Peter Koyote) wearing that fez and the trailer:



